# Understanding the graph of linear system solvers comparison

Tags: numerical-methods

[image]

What do you think what is the vertical axis here? I would guess it's the error but it's increasing with the iterations... Thank you.

Comment: Is there a link to the document this came from?

Comment: This is from the CD attachment of C.G. Broyden M.T. Vespucci - Kyrlov Solvers for Linear ALgebraic Systems. There is an appendix for the graphs, but it doesn't help. https://imgur.com/a/GTBfr8f

Comment: It could be a typo, a forgotten minus sign in setting the label format for the vertical axis. As per the appendix, RRR - relative recursive residual (some kind of a-posteriori error estimate?) and RTR - relative true residual, these are indeed error terms.

Comment: @LutzL I was thinking the same, that it is a typo. If you convert your comment to an answer I would accept it, otherwise I think I would delete this question.